# Django 1.7 migration cannot find app

Tags: django-migrations

I'm creating a data migration for app `Notification`, in here i'm using the reference of model, `Manager`, from app `accounts`

```
Manager = apps.get_model("accounts", "Manager")
```

It throws error :

```
    self.code(from_state.render(), schema_editor)
  File "/home/notifications/migrations/0004_auto_20150720_0127.py", line 12, in set_notification_setttings
    Manager = apps.get_model("accounts", "Manager")
  File "/home/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 202, in get_model
    return self.get_app_config(app_label).get_model(model_name.lower())
  File "/home/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 150, in get_app_config
    raise LookupError("No installed app with label '%s'." % app_label)
LookupError: No installed app with label 'accounts'
```

Although from shell i tried something like and it worked

```
>> from django.apps import apps
>> apps.get_app_config('accounts').get_model('Manager'.lower())
>> accounts.models.Manager
```

Any light on Why is it failing in case of migration ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your issue is probably already resolved but somebody else might come across this question.

If the Manager model is not in the same app where you are creating the migration you need to add the dependency for the app `accounts` in the migration. Example:

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):
    dependencies = [
        ('Current_App_Name', 'XYZ_Last_Migration_of_App'),
        ('accounts', '0012_auto_XYZ'),
        ...,
    ]`
    ...
```